# Wrapping a paragraph with `span` tag by 4 letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I require to wrap whole text by `span` tag by each 4 letters. I can able to split and join, but I could not able to wrap by 4 letters exactly. At present it's taking different count. What can I try next?

```js
const str = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";

const joined = str.split(' ').join('');

const reg = new RegExp(/(\w+)/, 'g');

const value = joined.replace(reg, '<span>$1</span>');

console.log(value)
```

Comment: You means `<span>Lore</span><span>mIps</span><span>umis</span>...` ?

Comment: @kyun yes, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `match()` to split the string into an array of substrings 4 letters each, after that use `map()` method to wrap each substring with a span tag.

```js
const str = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";

const substrings = str.match(/.{1,4}/g); // split the string into substrings containing four letters

const wrapped = substrings.map(substring => `<span>${substring}</span>`).join(''); // wrap each substring with a span tag and join the resulting array of strings

console.log(wrapped);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it works fine:

```js
const str = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";

    const joined = str.split(' ').join('');
    
    const reg = new RegExp(/(.{4})/, 'g');
    
    const value = joined.replace(reg, '<span>$1</span>');
    
    console.log(value)
```